# Have a higher-resolution flair for printing

Tags: feature-request, flair

For the Stack Overflow meetup today, I thought I would print out my [flair image](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600500/paulo-ebermann/flair) - one of these:

[image: combined-flair]  [image: so-flair]

But unfortunately they have a resolution of only 208×58 pixels, which is not quite enough to print them nicely.

Could we have a higher-resolution version of these images suitable for printing? (Maybe even a vector-graphics version allowing seamless zooming... but of course the fixed resolution of the Gravatar makes this complicated.)

I suppose this request comes a bit too late to have this implemented for today, but it would be nice to have anyway.

Comment: It's not *exactly* the same but for individual sites [the HTML flair is still available](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/600500.html)  and can be scaled more easily.

Comment: Why not making the flair with a vector and when you have to export it you just include a high-resolution gravatar? If that's not possible, just make everything vector and exclude the gravatar.

Comment: As soon as this gets implemented, we'll get a slew of Meta questions asking why the reputation score on their printed flair isn't updating. We'll tell them "caching".

Comment: Related: [SVG Flairs (In Addition To PNG Flairs)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65759/997587) and [Optimise Stack Exchange user flair for Retina displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131045/997587)

Comment: Related request on MSO: [Flair images low resolution on retina displays](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262704/1478931)