# flair - no html version on StackExchange?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, flair, combined-flair

StackOverflow HTML flair rendering is much better for readability than the PNG rendering on my system (Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) in Incognito mode - no extensions - on Mac OS X with no zoom):

[image: PNG flair]
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1.png or https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1.png
[image: HTML flair]
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1 or https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1

So I tried the same on StackExchange to get the combined flair:

[image: PNG flair]
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1.png or https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1.png
And found out that the HTML flair give a nice 404:
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1 or https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1

Can we get HTML flair on StackExchange too?
Or even better: can the PNG flair rendering be improved?

Comment: I guess you have zoom, or using a mobile device, because with 100% zoom or ordinary screen, there's no visible difference. The thing is that text quality is preserved on zooming, while ordinary images are just stretched. The solution is having the flair be served as .svg file, which is also scaling with zooming hence preserves the quality perfectly, e.g. see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/share-sprite-new.svg) - all of those are perfectly preserved on any zoom and any device.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've updated the question (I'm not using zoom). SVG would indeed be a solution if they were available (currently they are not). Do you know if there are plans for the future to serve them as SVG?

Comment: Yes there are two related feature request: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131045/optimise-stack-exchange-user-flair-for-retina-displays), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65759/svg-flairs-in-addition-to-png-flairs), neither are planned just yet. Not sure if your request can be considered duplicate of any of them, what is your opinion on this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure either. Conclusion is that there is quite a bit of flair work overdue (:

Comment: Very true. Already upvoted, let's hope something will be done. :)