# Add srcset to allowed img tag attributes?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown

According to [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), the only supported attributes on an `img` tag in Stack Exchange markdown are `src`, `width`, `height`, `alt`, and `title`.  Would it be possible to add `srcset` to the allowed attributes for the `img` tag?  Support for the `srcset` attribute seems pretty good based on http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset.

Comment: So now users have to think about optimising for mobile and large screen views as well as getting the image showing the right details in the first place?

Comment: What would you want to use this feature for? I suspect there would be better (as in easier to use and harder to abuse) ways to achieve your goal than to expose the full functionality of `srcset` to the end user.

Comment: @random I don't want users to have to do anything. I'm proposing that users be able to do something.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Ideally, I'd like the flair png in my profile to use higher-res versions only for clients that will actually make use of it. Right now, it's a 2x image because the 1x image was fuzzy on one of my monitors and it bugged me, but the 2x image is about three times the bytes.

Comment: [SVG flair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65759/svg-flairs-in-addition-to-png-flairs) would seem like a good solution for that particular problem. (As for uploaded images in posts, SE could in principle get their dimensions from imgur and automatically inject appropriate `srcset` attributes during Markdown parsing. Although actually serving the appropriately scaled image version might require some extra support from imgur -- their selection of pre-scaled image sizes is currently somewhat limited.)

Answer (score 6):

I'd be in favour (not a lot of people are going to use it, but why not allow it?) except for one problem: multiple src's would make abuse much more difficult to detect.

I could specify an innocent image at 1x (or whatever the "default" res is, I haven't used it so far) and an evil one at 4x.

Since the audience likely to see, and moderate, the 4x image is *much* smaller than that seeing the default image, bad content might go undetected for a long time.

An OP could not only *create* posts with evil content - they could even *edit* additional src's in images in *existing* posts without anyone with moderating rights noticing for a long time.

Comment: Admittedly, the likelihood of naive attackers discovering and using this is pretty slim. But it's pretty nasty just the same when it does happen.