# Please make the valuable flair™ higher quality

Tags: feature-request, flair, combined-flair, retina

Currently, we are provided with a PNG image, 208x58 pixels.

[image: Flair]

That's pretty small. Please can you make it higher quality? I'm thinking double the size in each direction - so it's similar in height to a banner advertisement. This would make it around 4x as valuable.

Unlike the [request for SVG flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65759/svg-flairs-in-addition-to-png-flairs), I request to keep the PNG flair, just improve its quality. This is because I believe it's much harder for the team to implement (I mean they've had nearly 7 years) and a bigger PNG is enough - if not perfect.

Comment: Why not ask for an SVG version?

Comment: @rene would be even better, but a) AFAIK they don't have SVG copies of the favicons (and if they do I've never found them) and b) It uses the gravatar image which is not infinitely scalable.

Comment: The only real way to retain quality is SVG, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, I *wanted* to make a flair generator with the API. Then bad JavaScript skills and an accidental infinite loop got me throttled with a back-off time of 12 hours, so... the thought was there, at least! :(

Comment: @JasonC Something like this: https://stackapps.com/questions/6932/seflair-an-hd-customisable-flair-for-your-stack-exchange-accounts Visible at https://timtjtim.co.uk/Flair/flair.html :P Perhaps I'll get my server to render those as higher quality images so anyone can use them.

Comment: (@Tim: unrelated but the MIT licence at the bottom of your flair page 404s.)

Comment: @Mat Yeah I think I changed the link for that (and I assumed it was only a localhost testing issue). I'll get on it.

Comment: Flair looks like poop.  Should be redesigned.

Comment: @JasonC See the answer I just posted. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: @Won't Have a look at the answer below - if you think that looks okay you can use those.

Comment: Is there an official reason for why this image has such low resolution?  Anyone that displays it is providing free advertising for SE, so why would SE want it to look bad?

Comment: We really need this. It is only looking worse over time as internet connections improve and people are expecting much higher quality images.

Comment: There is also the Stack APP at https://se-flair.2718.us https://se-flair.2718.us/4485506@5x.png

Answer (score 3):

I've done it! Kinda:

## [Good looking, higher quality Stack Exchange flairs!](https://stackapps.com/questions/7395/good-looking-higher-quality-stack-exchange-flairs)

I'm running an API to do this on my own server. It looks quite nice:

[image]

The example is at this url:

#### https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/askubuntu/69/292929

You can get yours at this url:

```
https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/SITENAME/USERID/COLOR
```

and check out [the Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/questions/7395/good-looking-higher-quality-stack-exchange-flairs) for more information.

Comment: What about network wide flair? (the one that shows the site icons)

Comment: @ColeJohnson The method I've used that's not feasible - requesting one favicon takes long enough - multiple would cause the first time generation (i.e. uncached) to take over 10 seconds for 8 favicons. At some point requests would start to timeout.

Comment: It redirects to a login screen: https://timtjtim.co.uk/InternalAccess/login.html

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Drat, that was an update gone wrong! Fixed it (almost, give me 5 mins to get favicons back)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones BTW you might find EEEEEE to be the best colour, or use https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=colour+picker&oq=colour+picker&aqs=chrome..69i57.1629j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 and the numbers starting with '#'.

Comment: Works now!  I like [purple](https://timtjtim.co.uk/API/1.0/flair/islam/17163/994499).  (:

Comment: looks like the app's down?